# How to validate that a date is X years in the past in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

I have registration form, I want to validate age for 18 year old only allowed.

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(
      color: Colors.grey[250],
      Icons.calendar_month_outlined),
  onPressed: () async {
    DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(1930),
        lastDate: DateTime.now());
    setState(() => pickedDate = pickedDate);
    if (pickedDate != null) {
      _dateOfBirth.text = pickedDate.toString().substring(0, 10);
    }
  },
),
```

I have this date picker, please tell me how to validate if picked date is valid (18 year old).

Comment: Heh... just make your date picker for birthdate end at 18 years ago, and then ask "are you sure?" if they enter the very end date. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have check with `isBefore` in `DateTime`.

```
bool isAdult(DateTime date) {
  final DateTime today = DateTime.now();
  final DateTime adultDate = DateTime(
    date.year + 18,
    date.month,
    date.day,
  );

  return adultDate.isBefore(today);
}
```